# Dell Inspiron 16 plus nvidia driver crashing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

I'm trying to install nvidia drivers on my inspiron 16 plus, with an rtx 3050. The laptop boots and works for a bit, but there are weird rainbow artifacts and then the screen dies.

The problem seems to be on both the 470 and 460 driver. I tried installing the drivers from the terminal, through the drivers menu and with the .run package, but they all have the same results.

How can I get my videocard running?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

The following assumes that the nvidia driver is working well enough to edit grub settings. If this is not the case, boot into recovery mode. Now remove existing nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
```

Edit the grub config:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And edit the following line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

*For nvidia-driver-495 `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"` seems to work great.*

Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Right now you should be able to boot normaly (not with secondary screen), but you can't use your graphics card. So to fix that:

Install nvidia drivers the 'normal' way:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx
```

xxx = 470 at time of writing.

Edit the grub config:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And edit the following line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1 i915.enable_psr=0"
```

I am not too sure about `i915.enable_psr=0`, but it seems to fix the screen flickering.

Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Edit nvidia config:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And uncomment (remove #) from the line:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

To clarify, I'm using 20.04. Later releases may rely more on wayland so the steps might change.